# Ошибка unreachable statement

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Прохожу урок на StartAndroid, возникла ошибка в коде, не могу понять как исправить, нужный класс импортирован, всё переписал как в примере, помогите разобраться. Ошибка  *unreachable statement* на строке:

```
AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
```

код:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    private static final int CM_DELETE_ID = 1;
    ListView lvData;
    DB db;
    SimpleCursorAdapter simpleCursorAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db = new DB(this);
        db.open();

        String[] from = new String[]{DB.COLUMN_IMG, DB.COLUMN_TEXT};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.ivImg, R.id.tvText};

        simpleCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item, null, from, to, 0);
        lvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvData);
        lvData.setAdapter(simpleCursorAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(lvData);
        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);


    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        db.addRec("sometext " + (simpleCursorAdapter.getCount() + 1), R.drawable.alligator);

        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, CM_DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.delete_record);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {

            AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

            db.delRec(acmi.id);

            getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new MyCursorLoader(this, db);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        simpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

    }

    static class MyCursorLoader extends CursorLoader {
        DB db;

        public MyCursorLoader(Context context, DB db) {
            super(context);
            this.db = db;
        }

        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = db.getAllData();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(18000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cursor;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
в этой строчке ошибка?

Comment: AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); 

В этой  unreachable statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unreachable statement  - недостижимый код. Ваш метод `onContextItemSelected()` начинается с оператора `return` и дальнейший код этого метода будет не доступен и никогда не выполнится, о чем вы и получаете ошибку от компилятора, нужно удалить либо первый `return`, либо код после него, если его выполнение не требуется:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == CM_DELETE_ID) {

        AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        db.delRec(acmi.id);

        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```