# Зачем нужна ошибка Unreachable statement?

Tags: java, компиляция, дизайн-языка

Зачем компилятор выдает эту ошибку? Что плохого в том что код не выполнится??

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка unreachable statement](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/638377/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-unreachable-statement)

Comment: @ИванГладуш, не дубликат. Вопрос зачем, а не как исправить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Компилятор выдает эту ошибку, чтобы предупредить программиста о том, данный код **никогда** не будет выполнен. Это нужно для того, чтобы не было проблем в том случае, когда вы ожидаете выполнение данной строки, но она не достигается.

Можно сказать, что нас защищают от потенциальной ошибки, которая может возникнуть в результате того, что не выполнится написанный код.

Comment: Специально чтобы _предупредить_ существуют _предупреждения_ ;)

Answer (score 1):

Если бы это была не ошибка, а предупреждение (кто вообще читает предупреждения?), или об этом вообще никак не сообщалось, то вы могли бы случайно не там вставить `return`, и удивляться почему у вас код работает не так как вы ожидаете.

Если вам (сейчас) не нужно, чтобы код выполнялся - закомментруйте его или вынесите блок кода в отдельный метод.

Comment: можно также if(false) { ... }